# Alternative to 'truss -p' instruction

Tags: unix, process, solaris, status, truss

I am looking for a command in Unix that returns the status of a process(active, dead, sleeping, waiting for another process, etc.)

is there any available?
A shell script maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try *pflags <pid>*, which will give you per-thread status information. Example:

```
root@weetbix # pflags $$
3384:   bash
        data model = _ILP32  flags = ORPHAN|MSACCT|MSFORK
 /1:    flags = ASLEEP  waitid(0x7,0x0,0xffbfefc0,0xf)
        sigmask = 0x00020000,0x00000000
```

Also check out the manpage for *pflags* to see other useful tools like *pstack*, *pfiles*, *pargs* etc.

Answer (score 3):

in linux, something like ps -p somepid --no-headers -o state should work, alternately you can look for the info in proc with grep ^State: /proc/somepid/status

Answer (score 0):

Playing with ps options doesn't give you what you need?